# JavaScript regex to skip sub pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I really can't figure this one out.

I have a string where I'm trying to match the three groups marked with opening and closing braces (e.g `{content}`), with the custom string I have below a double brace means it is escaped.

```
SetValue:{1} when {OVERVIEW{{}}.Debug=1} else {0}
// Here is an actual real life example
ValidWhen: {! Matches('^\\d{{3}}\\s\\d{{3}}\\s\\d{{3}}[\\s\\S]', COLLECTION.AccountNumber)} {Account Number must not be more than 9 numbers.}
```

I can't figure out a regex to match the second group as `{OVERVIEW{{}}.Debug=1}` instead of `{OVERVIEW{{` the closest I've got is using this regex as I thought I might be able to use the lookbehind to prevent it stopping on the double braces.

```
/{(?!\}).*?\}/
```

Is this even possible? Or do I need some more elaborate string parsing?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Not an exact duplicate. This one doesn't have nested braces.

Comment: What this `\\d{{3}}` regex means?

Comment: @nhahtdh your regex won't work if there is anything inside `{{}}` ..

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I have state my assumption that the regex only works for "valid input", though I do make an assumption that `{{}}` never appear outside `{}`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It's to do with the product it's used on, gets injected as a string, hence the double slash escape and the double braces indicate to escape a brace.

Comment: @nhahtdh works only for this input.. I don't know what do you mean by `valid input` ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex works for valid input<sup>1</sup>:

```
/{(?:[^{}]|{{|}})*}/
```

We simply disallow any `{}` inside braces, and allow only double `{{` and `}}`.

<sup>1</sup> Here are some input that the regex above may return *unexpected result*:

```
{{0}} text
```

This regex will match `{0}`, which is most likely incorrect.

```
{{ OVER}
```

Unbalaced braces and most likely invalid code.

```
{ A {B } C}
```

Nested braces - not sure if this is valid, but the regex above will grab `{B }`.

[**Demo on regex101**](http://regex101.com/r/nC5oC7/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
{[^}{]*}|{\S+}
```

Try this.   See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sK8oK9/6

Comment: Thanks but breaks down without the spaces e.g. matching `SetValue:{1}when{OVERVIEW{{}}.Debug=1} else {0}`

Comment: Appreciated but I think it still falls down, I've updated the question to add a more involved real example.